# Location of local resources

Tags: asp.net, resources

I have this piece of code in my aspx-file:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbEventName" runat="server" CssClass="required" Width="350px"></asp:TextBox><asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" Display="None" ControlToValidate="tbEventName" ErrorMessage="<%$Resources:EventNameMissing %>"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Now I'd like to edit "EventNameMissing" which appears to be a local resource. (The resource is already defined and contains a string)
I verified this by programmatically calling `GetLocalResourceObject("EventNameMissing");`, which returns the same string, as in my aspx-file.

However, I can't find the file the string's in. In my solution explorer there is an entry "App_LocalResources", but it's empty.
Where are those located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the local resources come from the database.
The following configuration is defined in Web.config:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="wwDbResourceProvider" type="Westwind.Globalization.wwDbResourceProviderSection" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
```